# Parsing Map values from a String in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, dictionary

Suppose I have a String like "[13:00,14:30], [18:10,18:40],[22:00,05:05]".
I want to produce a Map from the above String like

"13:00","14:30"

"18:10","18:40"

"22:00","05:05"

Now please suggest what is the efficient way to do it.

Thanx.

Comment: The efficient way is to start coding, then ask your question if it doesn't work. If it works and you're not sure it's efficient, you can opt for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take the below code as a hint:-

```
      public static void main(String args[]){
          String strVal="[13:00,14:30], [18:10,18:40],[22:00,05:05]";
          String strVal1=strVal.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
          System.out.println(strVal1);
          String[] array=strVal1.split(",");
          Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
          for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i=i+2){        
             map.put(array[i], array[i+1]); 
          }
          System.out.println(map);
}

Output:- 
13:00,14:30, 18:10,18:40,22:00,05:05
{22:00=05:05, 13:00=14:30,  18:10=18:40}
```